# Move to a div after page load. "onmouseover" works but "window.onload" does not

Tags: javascript, onclick, dojo, dom-events, onmouseover

I have a page (and divs) that are being dynamically generated and what I need for this page to do is to scroll to a particular div immediately after the page loads. What is screwy about this code is this...

The "button" code below, when you run the mouse over it (or `onclick`), works perfectly. It executes the `rolldownTo` function perfectly. However when I try to specify to specify the same action using `window.onload,` nothing happens. I have included both the "button " code and the `window.onload` below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Help</title>

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
    djConfig="usePlainJson : true, parseOnLoad: true">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.FilteringSelect");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
    dojo.require("dojo.window");


function rolldownTo(my_anchor){
    dojo.window.scrollIntoView(my_anchor);
}

window.onload=rolldownTo('car_help');
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs    /dojo/1.5/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>
</head>

<body class="claro">

<div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" region="center">
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="CAR HELP" selected=true>
           <button type=button id=button1 onmouseover="rolldownTo('car_help');">
             scroll to car_help
            </button>
            ........
            LOTS OF DIVS LIVE IN THIS DIV, INCLUDING MY TARGET "car_help"
            ........  
 </div>
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="BIKE HELP" selected=false>
     ........
            ........
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript">
.... LOTS OF CODE THAT GENERATES CONTENT FOR THE DIVS ABOVE
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Does anyone have an idea why a Javascript event like `onmouseover` or `onclick` would work perfectly but `window.onload` will not?

Comment: You probably already tried but have you tried moving the onload assignment to the bottom of the page after the page has loaded. That way you know that the content has been loaded. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page load doesn't mean the the DOM tree has been fully initialized which mean that your script cannot move the div unless the tree finish working, you must wait it until finished by using the javascript Event **DOMContentLoaded**.

In dojo, There is a function that can be called, it waits until the browser finish the DOM Tree, you can use it as :

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){rolldownTo('car_help');});
```

I hope this would work for you

Best Regards
NiL

Comment: This comment offers a good solution but the wrong explanation.  DOMContentLoaded actually fires *before* window.onload - the latter waits for images, etc. to finish, whereas DOMContentLoaded waits *only* for the DOM tree to be ready.  `dojo.addOnLoad` (also `dojo.ready` in 1.4+) waits for DOMContentLoaded in browsers that support it (not IE), and window.onload otherwise.  Ivo actually identified the problem correctly, but at any rate it's probably better to avoid window.onload altogether in favor of `dojo.addOnLoad` since I'm not sure if it might interfere with dojo's own loader logic.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is this line:

```
window.onload=rolldownTo('car_help');
```

You're not assigning the function `rolldownTo` to as the callback for the `onload` event, you're **executing** the function and assigning the return value, in this case `undefined`.

You need to wrap the call with an anonymous function in order to make it work:

```
window.onload = function(){ rolldownTo('car_help'); };
```

Now the anonymous function will get called by the `onload` event and then call `rolldownTo`.

So much for the problem, as NiL has halfway pointed out (`onload` fires *after* DOMLoaded) you can use `dojo.addOnLoad` instead of `window.onload` here, but you still have to use the anonymous function for the reasons stated above.